# Установка и настройка OpenVPN на Centos 7

Tags: centos, openvpn

При вызове

```
systemctl status openvpn@server.service
```

Выдает ошибки:

```css
â— openvpn@server.service - OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-05-11 09:42:33 EDT; 16min ago
  Process: 2909 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2909 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain openvpn[2909]: Thu May 11 09:42:33 2017 WARNING: cannot stat file 'server.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain openvpn[2909]: Options error: --key fails with 'server.key': No such file or directory
May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain openvpn[2909]: Thu May 11 09:42:33 2017 WARNING: cannot stat file 'ta.key': No such file or directory (errno=2)
May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain openvpn[2909]: Options error: --tls-auth fails with 'ta.key': No such file or directory
May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain openvpn[2909]: Options error: Please correct these errors.
May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain openvpn[2909]: Use --help for more information.
May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On server.
May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit openvpn@server.service entered failed state.
May 11 09:42:33 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: openvpn@server.service failed.
```

Comment: перевод: файлы `server.key` и `ta.key` не найдены. вероятно, неправильно вы сконфигурировали openvpn.